# Drop Down a Combobox on button click

Tags: c#, button, drop-down-menu, combobox

Hello is there a away to drop down my combobox using a button click?

because I'm planning to use a combobox and a button so that if the user clicks the button the combobox will drop down.

I need a button because I'm using it for a touch screen device. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the DroppedDown property of ComboBox

```
comboBox1.DroppedDown= true;
```